# Trying to mass replace files from one directory to where the file is found in another. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I have 200+ files in a single directory that I need to first search for in another directory with subs and replace after it is found. File names are the same. Content/size is usually different. Last time I had to do this I had a linux environment so I put together a command. I have no idea how to do this in windows.

Comment: Google directory synchronization or similar terms.  There are lots of utilities that will do this, if I understand correctly.  Depending on need, XCOPY might be sufficient.  From a command prompt, type XCOPY /? for details.

Comment: Whenever I need this, I always use TeraCopy. Its a free copy program that supports testing for inconsistencies based on MD5 hashes. You copy the content from one folder to the other, and select Older only. It will then copy only the files that are different. A test at the end of the copy ensures that both locations are the same. If not, you can clean up the list of files to copy to only those that were different and copy those again.

Comment: xcopy would work if I was just moving all files from X:\ to Y:\ what I need to do is search Y:\ for X:\file.txt and when the file Y:\sub\dir\file.txt is found replace it.

Comment: EDIT: I missed the part where the destination is in sub directories. Not sure this can be easily done in windows.

Comment: replace command will work, I just have to figure out how to make it run through all the files in the x:\ directory.

Comment: for /r %i in (*) do replace %~nxi z:\ /S /P  it is slow, but time isn't important.

Comment: Let me make sure I have this straight: You have one folder with a bunch of files in its root (no sub-directories), and another folder with a bunch of files scattered throughout its structure (some in sub-directories). You want to find the file in the second folder (or its sub-directories) which matches each file in the first folder, and overwrite the first folder's copy with the second one?

Comment: Iszi, close. I need to take the file from the first directory and overwrite the file in the second location where ever that may be in the sub structure.

Comment: Oh. Then my script is roughly reversed. Hang on.

Comment: There. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following PowerShell script should do the job. It's probably far from optimal, since it's doing a full recursive search of the origin folder for each file, so you might want to look into tweaking it a bit. I strongly suggest testing it with non-critical data and folders first. I did some testing with a small set of sample files and it ran fine, but the files in your environment may not be so simple.

Note that there may be some unexpected behavior if a file you're looking for does not exist in the origin folder, or if there are multiple files in the origin folder which have the same name as the one being sought.

```
$DestDIR = 'C:\Destination'
$OrigDIR = 'C:\Origin'

Get-ChildItem $OrigDir | ForEach-Object {
    $OrigName = $_.Name
    $OrigPath = $_.FullName

    Get-ChildItem $DestDIR -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $OrigName} | ForEach-Object {
        $DestPath = $_.FullName
        Copy-Item $OrigPath $DestPath -Force
    }
}
```